# How to animate the transform of an element so that it falls from above coming towards the screen?

Tags: css, rotation, css-animations, css-transforms

I have an element that should come towards the user in front of the screen but also like falling from above.

I have tried transitioning from `rotateX(-90deg)` to `rotateX(0)` and from `rotateX(360deg)` to `rotateX(270deg)`, but it does not look the way I want.

Also I do not what would be a good way to search for this on Google.

## Sketch

[image: sketch]

## Source code

```css
body {
  margin: 0 0;
}

.my-class-here {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  animation-name: header-anim;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes header-anim {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(270deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class-here">
  TEST
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct your `transform-origin` and add some perspective:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 0;
}

.my-class-here {
  animation: header-anim 2s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin:top; /* don't forget this */
}

@keyframes header-anim {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class-here">
  TEST
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [this](http://animista.net/play/entrances/swing-in/swing-in-top-fwd) is what you're looking for.

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide-in-fwd-tr {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1400px) translateY(-800px) translateX(1000px);
            transform: translateZ(-1400px) translateY(-800px) translateX(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0) translateX(0);
            transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0) translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-in-fwd-tr {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1400px) translateY(-800px) translateX(1000px);
            transform: translateZ(-1400px) translateY(-800px) translateX(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0) translateX(0);
            transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0) translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great link! I use this now: https://animista.net/play/entrances/swing-in/swing-in-top-fwd. If you change the answer to link to that animation I will accept your answer.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer but I have chosen the solution of Temani Afif because it is more simple and has a greater frame rate.